# Python I2C error with SMBus and GY-521 (MPU6050), bytes omitted resulting in crash

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

I am using an GY521 (MPU6050) to test the I2C interface. I am able to read data from it, but sometimes, randomly, the python interpreter would crash: `IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error`.

I have used a logic analyser to look at what's going on and compared the signals with the [Datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf).

I have been able to detect the address of the module using the code `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`

My script ([that i modified from this tutorial](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/measuring-rotation-and-acceleration-raspberry-pi/)) is the following. Basically, each 10ms i want to read from the gyro_x register (there's a `time.sleep(0.01`) after each command):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import smbus
import math
import time
 
# Register
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c
    
bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # bus = smbus.SMBus(0) fuer Revision 1
address = 0x68       # via i2cdetect

bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)
 
def read_byte(reg):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, reg)
 
def read_word(reg):
    h = bus.read_byte_data(address, reg)
    l = bus.read_byte_data(address, reg+1)
    value = (h << 8) + l
    return value
 
def read_word_2c(reg):
    val = read_word(reg)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val
 
def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b))
 
def get_y_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(x, dist(y,z))
    return -math.degrees(radians)
 
def get_x_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(y, dist(x,z))
    return math.degrees(radians)

def main(args):
    while(1):
        gyro_xout = read_word_2c(0x43)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Below is what is supposed to happen according to the datasheet:
[image]

Below are the signals that i get when it's working aswell as when it crashes:
[image]
[image]

As you can notice, in the last (crash) image, there's a missing `[0x43 + ACK]` command between the Write and the Read commands. This happens every time after a few seconds. This is why the python interpreter crashes since it's the last signal to be recorded on my logic analyzer.

Why does the Raspberry Pi **randomly** acts this way?
How can i overcome this problem?
Are there any other more reliable libraries for I2C communication (in the future, i plan to use an Arduino as a slave)?

Thank you in advance.

PS. I used pull-up resistors on the breadboard that i'm using (even tho the documentation says it's not necessary). I also used some really small capacitors (150Pf) to try to filter some noise that i was having (according to [this source](https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/WhitePapers/HM/ImprovingNoiseImmunityforSerialInterface.ashx?document_id=50728)).

Comment: I expect there are dozens of Python scripts to read the 6050.  Could you try an unmodified one and see if it works?

Comment: "IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error" is a common I2C communication error. If it is intermittent, then it is difficult to troubleshoot. I usually have two or more sets of ports, wiring, and device to do swap troubleshooting. For Rpi4B, I usually swap two I2C ports (the first two ports available). I also swap wiring, eg rewire, or change lengths. I once repeatedly compare 16+ I2C MCP23017s, and found that a couple of them have Error121 many more times than the average. BTW, there is a 400pF limit on one bus, so (1) not to put too many devices on same bus, (2) Remove all pull ups except one.

Comment: @joan I have tried using the [following library](https://pypi.org/project/mpu6050-raspberrypi/) on the raspberry pi. My main function (`while True:`) reads data `temp = sensor.get_temp()`, then it prints it `print(temp)` and then it sleeps for 10ms `time.sleep(0.01)`. After about 4 seconds, i get the  `IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error`. When looking at my logic analyzer, the data should be "write, ack, read, nack" for the first and second bytes. But on the logic analyzer, i notice that the second byte is actually "write, **nack**, read, nack". This causes the script to crash.

Comment: @tlfong01 I tried reading the signal using an oscilloscope and i noticed that adding an extra capacitor on the data (SDA) helped with this issue. I noticed that one the data, there are small voltage spikes each clock tick, and maybe this spikes ended up beyond the low voltage treshold. Now, with 300pF on the data, the whole acquisition can go a few minutes before crashing. I'm not really sure how to filter out these spikes, because adding a passive RC filter might lower the voltage on the data below the treshold. Also, sometimes i had to unplug and re-plug the MPU to reset it completely.

Comment: @C Tal, yes, I agree you can, by trials and errors, add little bypass/decoupling caps here and there, might be a good compromise/tradeoff. I forgot if I earlier suggest to (1) lower I2C speed to 100kHz or even 50, 10kHz to confirm it is the root cause, (2) remove ALL pullups in the modules except the 1k8 resistors in Rpi4B, also to confirm the pullup s do cause trouble.